# Best Sql Server IDE for scripting / development needs

Tags: sql-server, ide

I am looking for the best Sql Server IDE for scripting / development needs. Must haves:

- Visual GUI for creating complex queries
- Intellisense for all db objects
- Auto-format capability to format SQL script to a particular format / coding standard.
- SELECT Sql output to .xls, .txt with custom choices in delimiters / format

Cost is not an issue. When you make a recommendation, can you state why you prefer it, and what other IDEs you have tried before. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Management Studio with SQL Assistant (www.softtreetech.com) or SQL Prompt (www.red-gate.com)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking at [SQL Everywhere](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/sqleverywhere/default.aspx). I have completely moved off of MS SQL Studio Management tool. The biggest advantage to SQL Everywhere for me is auto-complete (Intelisense) even against a SQL 2005 server. The format SQL feature is ok.

Comment: This is a 3 year old conversation, but since you stirred it up: I agree. It's got a lot of great features like you say, and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

Anything wrong with the management studio that comes with Sql Server?  The 2008 version meets all your requirements.

[edit]: I take it back: it can do autoformatting in the right circumstances, but it's painful and to my knowledge doesn't allow you to specify the coding standard.  Also, the intellisense is weak.

Comment: If you add some of the Red Gate tools, it would meet all of the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

try [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Try out

- [EMS SQL MANAGER Lite Version](http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/mssql/manager/download)
- [Toad For SQL Server](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver.htm)

I personally like EMS SQL Manager Lite, its not so lite in making your job easier, trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

ApexSQL [Edit](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_edit.asp). Not wild about their GUI query editor, but great on intellisense and formatting. Also includes options to copy out of the result set to Excel, CSV, and HTML via clipboard and some handy custom column copying tools. I'm practically crippled in SSMS because ApexSQL Edit has me so spoiled.

Comment: do you still use SQL Edit over SSMS? I'm looking into this application for the dev team here, and haven't been able to find much info on if it truly is worth the cost. It seems Apex is more affordable than Red Gate products....

Comment: I do still use ApexSQL Edit over SSMS. With ApexSQL releasing a lot of the Edit functionality as add-ins for SSMS, it may be hard to justify the cost of the full product, but I still like Edit better.

Answer (score 0):

As a well-performing tool for SQL developers I can recommend [dbForge Studio for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/). It matches all your requirements.
Specifically it has:
 - Visual query builder that enables creating complex queries
 - Intellisense that is comparable one provided by SQL Prompt
 - SQL script formatting with multiple options
 - SELECT output export to .xls and .txt plus 6 other formats (has wizard for export customization)